# Problem with displaying correct hidden field

Tags: php, html

This is my HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
    <?php
        $skillSubCategory = $skills->showSkills(24);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($skillSubCategory); $i++) {
    ?>

<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="<?php echo $skillSubCategory[$i]['skill_id']; ?>" />

    <?php echo $skillSubCategory[$i]['title']; ?>

<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br />

    <?php } ?>

</form>

    <?php if (isset($_POST['add'])) {
            echo $_POST['skillid'];
    } ?>
```

Resulting source code:

```
<form method="POST" action=""> 

<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="25" /> 

    Animal Grooming
    25
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br /> 


<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="26" /> 

    Dog Trainer
    26
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br /> 


<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="27" /> 

    Dog Walking
    27
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br /> 


<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="28" /> 

    Vet
    28
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br /> 


<input type="hidden" name="skillid" value="29" /> 

    Beekeeping
    29
<input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br /> 


</form>
```

What it looks like:

[image]

I get number 29 for any button clicked. Any ideas what's wrong? Why the correct number wont show up when i click add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use the buttons themselves(without changing their values):

```
<input type="submit" name="skillid[25]" value="add" />
<input type="submit" name="skillid[26]" value="add" />
<input type="submit" name="skillid[27]" value="add" />
```

To retrieve the submitted value(its not the value in this case, its the first key of the posted array):

```
if(isset($_POST['skillid']) && is_array($_POST['skillid']))
{
   echo key($_POST['skillid'])
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Because when you have multiple fields with the same `name` attribute in a form, the last one always takes precedence (with the exception of submit buttons -- the one clicked will be the only one considered).  So the last hidden input with the name `skillid` will always be sent to the server.

When using forms like this, you usually have to use separate forms for each button.  Alternatively, change the `value` attribute of each button and consider that from your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

to:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
```

then change the condition to:

```
if (isset($_POST['add']) && isset($_POST['skillid'])) {
```

**EDIT**: use the `<option>` tag instead

```
<select name="skillid">
 <option value="25">Animal Grooming</option>
 <option value="26">Dog Trainer</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Your PHP code now will be:

```
<form method="POST" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
 <?php
 $skillSubCategory = $skills->showSkills(24);
 <select name="skillid">
 for ($i = 0; $i < count($skillSubCategory); $i++) { ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $skillSubCategory[$i]['skill_id']; ?>"><?php echo $skillSubCategory[$i]['title']; ?></option>
 <?php } ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="add" value="add" /><br />
</form>

if (isset($_POST['add']) && isset($_POST['skillid'])) {
    echo $_POST['skillid'];
} ?>
```

Comment: Thanks I just did that but im still getting 29 for any button clicked?

Comment: Edited. use the `<option>` tag, it will be easier and cleaner.

Comment: Nah, i'd rather do it the way it is because im already using a drop down for main categories. these are sub categories. Thanks anyway.